# How can I automatically add some local variables info to a C-x C-f new (.tex) file?

Tags: auctex, local-variables

I use `auctex` to edit my `.tex` files. Each time I create a new file `.tex` file *via* C-x C-f, I want to insert two local variables informations:

```
% Local Variables:
% coding: utf-8-unix
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

Until now, I do M-x `add-file-local-variable` two times. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: First question here. Hope the formating is ok. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you prefer setting this as file local variables or setting a global default value?

Comment: @giordano On my computer, those settings are default settings. But I want to keep those settings in my files, in case I work on an other computer. (If I understand correctly your question)

Comment: Yes, that was my question, and your answer is perfectly fine :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks) to achieve this.  Use the one you need as described in [auctex documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html#Modes-and-Hooks).  Here we check the file extension so that we don't do that for eg `.sty` files.  Also, we test the `buffer-read-only` variable before modifying the buffer.

The `goto-char` at the end ensures point is set at beginning of buffer.

```el
(defun my/add-auctex-file-variables ()
  (interactive)
  (if (and (not buffer-read-only)
           (string= (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name)) "tex"))
   (progn
     (add-file-local-variable 'coding 'utf-8-unix)
     (add-file-local-variable 'TeX-engine 'luatex)
     (goto-char (point-min)))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/add-auctex-file-variables)
```

Also, as can be seen on `add-file-local-variable` docstring (display it with `C-h f add-file-local-variable`) any setting of the variable is first deleted, so there's no risk of accumulating such definitions.

A possible pitfall is that the file is marked as modified even if nothing has actually changed.

Comment: @cjorssen Sure, just add `(goto-char 1)` at end of `my/...` function (before the closing `)`).

Comment: @cjorssen The docstring of `add-file-local-variable` (use `C-h f add-file-local-variable`) says any setting of the variable is first deleted, if that's what you ask.

Comment: @cjorssen Yes, see updated answer, as well as pitfall.

Comment: The first character of a buffer is `(point-min)`, not necessarily `1`.

Comment: @giordano Good point.

Comment: The pitfall you mentioned is finally a bit annoying after a month of every day usage. Do you see a simple workaround? Thanks.

Comment: @cjorssen You could add a `(set-buffer-modified-p nil)` as the last instruction in `progn`.  For your use case it would be ok (you 'll edit new files so they will be marked modified anyway).

Comment: Great. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.